# Handling D3v3 Labels Overlapping

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, scatter-plot

Hi,
I'm developing a visual like a scatter plot using D3.js it has around 20k points without labels. I want to show the labels for the filtered data. I modified a function to avoid labels overlapping. It works but if I have a large number of points after applying the filter it cause crush the browser !!
Any ideas to improve the algorithm ? or to use the force function in D3v3 to do the job ?

```
function arrangeLabels(svg) {
    var move = 1;
    while(move > 0) {
        move = 0;
        svg.selectAll(".dotB")
        .each(function() {                                
            var that = this,
                a = this.getBoundingClientRect();
            svg.selectAll("text.dotB")
               .each(function() {
                   if (this != that) {
                   var b = this.getBoundingClientRect();
                   if ((Math.abs(a.left - b.left) * 2 < (a.width + b.width)) &&
                      (Math.abs(a.top - b.top) * 2 < (a.height + b.height))) {
                          var dy = (a.bottom + b.height)+2,
                              move += Math.abs(dy);
                          d3.select(this).attr("y", dy);
                          a = this.getBoundingClientRect();
                    }
                }
            });
        }) 
    }
```

I found this method to solve the overlapping issue using D3v4 https://walkingtree.tech/d3-quadrant-chart-collision-in-angular2-application/ any idea how to do the same in D3v3 ?!

Comment: If possible avoid multiple calls to `.getBoundingClientRect()` within nested loops. That is a very expensive operation when it comes to performance. Have a look at [*"Rendering: repaint, reflow/relayout, restyle"*](http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/) and [*"What forces layout / reflow"*](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is with the if logic:

```js
if (
    (Math.abs(a.left - b.left) * 2 < (a.width + b.width)) &&
    (Math.abs(a.top - b.top) < a.height + b.height)
) {
    var dy = (a.bottom + b.height)+2,
    move += Math.abs(dy);
    d3.select(this).attr("y", dy);
    a = this.getBoundingClientRect();
}
```

Comment: you can format you code using code block that will make you answer look good